# Strange behavior of datetimes when loaded into pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I'm trying to construct simple DataFrames. Both have a date whereas the first has one additional column:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

a = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
        [dt.datetime(2018, 1, 10), 5.0]]), columns=['date', 'amount'])

print(a)

# date_dt   amount
# 2018-01-10 00:00:00   5

b = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
        [dt.datetime(2018, 1, 10)]]), columns=['date'])

print(b)

# date_dt
# 2018-01-10
```

Why are the dates interpreted differently (with and without time)? It gives me problems when I later try to apply merges.

Comment: try: `a['date'] = pd.to_datetime(a['date'])`, this will allow you to merge. Even i'm waiting for an answer about your question. When I'm running `a['date'] = pd.to_datetime(a['date'])` result is : `datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 10, 0, 0)`  and for `b.date.iloc[0]` , answer is `Timestamp('2018-01-10 00:00:00')` . This is the reason you were not able to merge.

Comment: Thanks. That works. Still I would like to find out what happened when loading the data :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so here is what happens. I will use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

a_val = np.array([[dt.datetime(2018, 1, 10), 5.0]])

a = pd.DataFrame(a_val, columns=['date', 'amount'])

b_val = np.array([[dt.datetime(2018, 1, 10)]])
b = pd.DataFrame(b_val, columns=['date'])
```

I just split the contents of the pd dataframes and call to the dataframe themselves. First let's print thr `a_val` and `b_val` variables:

```
print(a_val, b_val)
# output: [[datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 10, 0, 0) 5.0]] [[datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 10, 0, 0)]]
```

So still good, the object are datetime.datetime.

Now let's access the values of the dataframe with `.values`:

```
print(a.values, b.values)
# output: [[datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 10, 0, 0) 5.0]] [['2018-01-10T00:00:00.000000000']]
```

Things are messed up here. Let's print the type of the date:

```
print(type(a.values[0][0]), type(b.values[0][0]))
# output: <class 'datetime.datetime'> <class 'numpy.datetime64'>
```

Ok, that's the thing: since in the second dataframe you just have a date object, and you call `np.array()`, the date is cast to a `numpy.datetime64` object, which has a different formatting. Instead, in the first dataframe you have a datetime object plus an int, and the code left them as is.

Short version: if you have a collection of different objects like dates, strings, int etc. use a list, not a numpy array

Answer (score 1):

Both columns in `a` are objects because of the numpy array that's an intermediate (and is of type `object`). I'd think that not implicitly interpreting mixed objects is probably good behavior.

```
a = pd.DataFrame([[dt.datetime(2018, 1, 10), 5.0]], columns=['date', 'amount'])
```

This seems to be more along the lines of what you want.